# range of ssh tunnel port

Tags: debian, port, ssh-tunnel

I use ssh tunneling with : `ssh -i <my_file> -R *:0:localhost:80 <my_name>@<host>`.

With the port = 0, the server assign me a port. How does the server choose and how can I config the range ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can't specify to `ssh` the server side port range to pick from, certainly not on the client side.  Assuming some *nix like system on the server, you should be able to set the ephemeral port range in `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range`.

Perhaps more usefully, you might just want to get the port assigned on the server side, which has been discussed [here](https://superuser.com/questions/304142/how-to-determine-the-port-allocated-on-the-server-for-a-dynamically-bound-openss) and [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/402852/reverse-ssh-tunnel-how-can-i-send-my-port-number-to-the-server).

Answer (score 2):

When the OS assigns a port to a TCP or UDP endpoint, it uses the [ephemeral port range](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port). Operating systems will allocate an unused port number from this range in some arbitrary fashion. It may choose a number randomly. Or it might just start with the low end of the range and assign the first number which isn't in use.

[This page](http://www.ncftp.com/ncftpd/doc/misc/ephemeral_ports.html) describes how to view and change the range on several different operating systems. On Linux, you can view and change the range by accessing `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range`:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range 
1024 4999

# echo "49152 65535" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range
```

Alternately, you can use `sysctl` to view or set the key `net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range`.